# How many tiles does a light horse take up?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Looking at PFSRD, all it lists for [Horse, Light](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/horse) is Large Animal. Large creatures normally take up 4 tiles: 2x2. However, in various places on the internet I have seen a horse referred to as a "long" large and suggesting it takes up just 2 tiles: 2x1. This has usually been in reference to squeezing rules or moving a horse through narrow spaces.

Am I missing something in the rules that allows for this interpretation? Or is it just a more common house ruling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A horse *is* “Large (long)”. But that has nothing to do with the (horizontal) Space of the horse.

A Large creature has a Space of a 10’ × 10’ square, period. All creatures’ Spaces are always square. A rectangular space would require that you track the creature’s facing, which the game does not (by default, anyway, and every variant I have seen to do so has been poorly thought through).

A Large (tall) creature also has a 10’ natural reach.

A Large (long) creature has only a 5’ natural reach (the same as a Medium (tall) creature).

[This page](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/space-reach-threatened-area-templates) has all the official rules about Spaces and Reach and so on, including entries for both Large (long) and Large (tall). It also has handy grids depicting the Space and threatened areas with and without a reach weapon for creatures of both those sizes.